# Making two lists, matching and not-matching specific file types

Tags: bash, files

I have a bash function where the arguments are files.  Thus the following print statement gives

```
opts="$@"
echo "$fargs"

Result:
linge-cellar.rc linge-cellar.rc~ linge-checkn.rc linge-checkn.rc~ linge-comint.rc linge-comint.rc~ linge-comseq.rc linge-comseq.rc~ linge-console.rc linge-console.rc~ linge-curiplaya.rc linge-curiplaya.rc~ linge-dircolors.rc linge-dircolors.rc~ linge-firefly.rc linge-firefly.rc~ linge-mosaic.rc linge-mosaic.rc~ linge-profile.rc opcon-cellar.rc~
```

I have two arrays `incl` and `excl` that stores file types to process.

```
Example: incl=( .rc )
```

I want to make two lists. One that has the files matching the file types in the array  `incl` (e.g. files with `.rc` extension). and another list that has the file names that fails the file type matching (e.g. files with `.rc~` extention).

Have started with a simple loop

```
  fargs="$@"
  local f ty aggr=()
  for f in $fargs; do
    for ty in "${incl[@]}"; do
      [[ "$f" =~ *${ty}$ ]] && aggr+=( "$f" )
    done
  done  

  echo "$fargs"

  echo
  echo "${incl[@]}"

  echo
  echo " aggr:"
  echo " ${aggr[*]}"
```

But something is wrong because I always get an empty `aggr` array.

```
dvorak linge-cellar.rc linge-cellar.rc~ linge-checkn.rc linge-checkn.rc~ linge-comint.rc linge-comint.rc~ linge-comseq.rc linge-comseq.rc~ linge-console.rc linge-console.rc~ linge-curiplaya.rc linge-curiplaya.rc~ linge-dircolors.rc linge-dircolors.rc~ linge-firefly.rc linge-firefly.rc~ linge-mosaic.rc linge-mosaic.rc~ linge-profile.rc opcon-cellar.rc~

.rc

 aggr:
```

Comment: In zsh, you could do something like this: [Is there a simple way to get array of all arguments that do not begin with a hyphen?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/114266/65304). In bash, I don't know a way to do it without looping over the elements of the `opts` array explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you are mixing regular expression syntax (the `$` line anchor) with glob pattern syntax (the leading `*` wildcard), as you can verify with a simple test:

```
$ ty=.rc; [[ foo.rc =~ *${ty}$ ]] ; echo $?
2
```

(the exit status of a syntactically valid test should be either 0 or 1).

Your test can either be

```
[[ "$f" =~ ${ty}$ ]]    # regex
```

or

```
[[ "$f" = *${ty} ]]     # glob pattern
```

As well, `fargs="$@"` is a scalar assignment; your unquoted `for f in $fargs` then splits the (string) variable on whitespace - which will break if any of the filenames contains whitespace. You should use `fargs=("$@")` and then `for f in "${fargs[@]}"`. Alternatively, just loop over the positional parameters directly, either `for f in "$@"` or, POSIXLY, just `for f`:

```
#!/bin/bash

myfunc () {

  local f ty aggr=()
  for f do
    for ty in "${incl[@]}"; do
      [[ "$f" = *${ty} ]] && aggr+=( "$f" )
    done
  done

  printf '%s\n' "${aggr[@]}"
}

incl=( .rc )

myfunc linge-cellar.rc linge-cellar.rc~ linge-checkn.rc linge-checkn.rc~ \
       linge-comint.rc linge-comint.rc~ linge-comseq.rc linge-comseq.rc~ \
       linge-console.rc linge-console.rc~ linge-curiplaya.rc linge-curiplaya.rc~ \
       linge-dircolors.rc linge-dircolors.rc~ linge-firefly.rc linge-firefly.rc~ \
       linge-mosaic.rc linge-mosaic.rc~ linge-profile.rc opcon-cellar.rc~
```

Testing:

```
$ ./myscript
linge-cellar.rc
linge-checkn.rc
linge-comint.rc
linge-comseq.rc
linge-console.rc
linge-curiplaya.rc
linge-dircolors.rc
linge-firefly.rc
linge-mosaic.rc
linge-profile.rc
```

---

In zsh, you can avoid the inner loop by applying a `${name:#pattern}` parameter expansion to the positional parameter array, with `M` modifier to remove non-matching elements (the default, without `M`, removes matching elements):

```
#!/bin/zsh

myfunc () {

  local ty aggr=()

  for ty in ${incl[@]}; do
    aggr+=( ${(M)@:#*${ty}} )
  done

  print -rC1 ${aggr[@]}
}
```

See this similar Unix & Linux answer [Is there a simple way to get array of all arguments that do not begin with a hyphen?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/114266/65304)